# Static variable set, but not gettable - Class loading issue ( possibly?)

Tags: java, static, classloading

This is very strange to me:

1) I have a class

```
public class Data {
    private static String name;

    public static String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public static void setName (String n){
        Data.name = n;
    }
}
```

this class variable name is set correctly during my server ( J2EE app in WAS liberty) startup - I wanted to cache this data during the whole server lifecycle.

2) but when I hit an URL that eventually invokes a code that does a getter:

```
Data.getName(); // this returns null??
```

Can anyone think of a possible reason? Not be able to debug also, I am very frustrated.

---

To illustrate my problem more, let me show my project structure:

EAR

CommonJar

WAR1         WAR2

My Data.java is in CommonJar. This Data.java is initialized in WAR1 during the server startup triggered by a Listener registered in web.xml, and from here I saw it is set and I saw the non-null value using Data.getName().-- this is my step 1 in my original post.

Then I have a restful HelloWorld Service in WAR2. And when I call into this HelloWorld service, I see Data.getName() returns null. -- this is my step 2 in my original post. Don't even think anything like syntax type of easy error, because it is not that.

My theory is: it seems that Data.java is loaded by classloader in WAR1 in step 1 and then WAR 2 in my step 2, and Step 2 loaded an empty Data class.

To verify if this theory is correct, I moved Data.java initialization step into the WAR2, (and again I saw it is set and I saw the non-null value using Data.getName()), the difference is that when I call into this HelloWorld service, I saw Data.getName() returns the expected non-null value. This step is what I call my troubleshooting breakthrough because it seems to indicate my theory was correct. (but I can't fix the issue by moving the code in my real problem fix)

Then the question is how to fix and how to visually see which class is loaded by which class loader and when? Also based on WAS Liberty doc, the default class loader will be parentsfirst, which means Data.java should be loaded by the parent ( in this case, EAR), so I shouldn't have my problem the first place.

Anyone, please guide how to further to see the problem and fix it? Thanks.

Comment: If the get fails and you cannot debug, how do you know that the variable is being set correctly during server startup?

Comment: make it `final` and see what happens. It sounds like you want it final anyway

Comment: see there are two steps: Step 1, I set the variable in the server startup, in this step I saw the variable "name" is set and gettable 2. Then I issue a URL request, in this step, the get returns a null. It seems like to me there are two copies of Data class loaded in these two steps.

Comment: You could declare the `name` variable as `private String name = "unset"` and then your getName method would show whether or not the setName method was ever called.

Answer (score 0):

Your getName() function is declared with no return type, yet attempts to return a string.

Comment: As does the setName() method, which should be declared void.

Comment: it is a typing error. It should return a type of String. This is my first question, not sure how to correct this error.

Comment: correct, typing error, sorry for that. But this is not cause to my issue

Answer (score 0):

try out this one

```
public class Data {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.out.println("setting name 'Stack Overflow'");
        Data.setName("Stack Overflow");
        System.out.println("now getting the setted name");
        System.out.println(Data.getName());
    }

    private static String name;

    public static String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public static void setName(String n) {
        Data.name = n;
    }
}
```

> Output:

```
setting name 'Stack Overflow'
now getting the setted name
Stack Overflow
```

In your code, you `defined no return types` to your `methods`.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. Your flow, of course, will work- it is all in the one java process, you set it and of course you will get it out. This just works as in my step 1 ( while I had a typing error). The problem exists in my second step where I can't get it out. The error is more subtle than it appears to be and particularly we have to think about in my second step ( after the server started up) when I submited a URL request which invoks the getter method, what can be possibly happened to this Data class which was populated and then now become empty. I have spend more than 10.

Comment: did you set the value before getting it

Comment: yes, as I indicated, in my first step, I saw it set and also got it correctly.

Comment: From where you are setting and getting it in server.

Comment: I appreciate your efforts. My real code is over complex and now I am using Data.java as a simple concept to indicate the issue. And simply put, during the server startup, I am using the setter  and getter I got the data, but when I use a URL invoke the getter, the same Data.java returns null for that getter. No way to load my 10M code to you in any way. What could be the reason that lead the class behaves like "stateless"?